# How to get current transaction details for a user in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

ASSET_TRANSFER_TABLE

```
 TRANSFER_ID  TRANSFER_DATE  ASSET_ID   STOCK_TAG  TRANSFER_FROM_ID  TRANSFER_TO_ID  
    111         dd/mm/yyyy      2122      222-222        Roy                Jina
```

Refering to the above table if a user has more than one asset in his/her account,the details for both the transaction has to be displayed.second,only the current transaction is to be displayed ie. previous trans where the same user used to hold an asset but it has been transferred to some other user,that the **past transaction details should be omitted**.

```
The result should display Transfer Id,Transfer Date,Asset ,Transfer to Id.
```

If anyone could help with this I would be really thankful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create separate query that gets the latest `TRANSFER_DATE` for each `AssetID`. Try something like this,

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT AssetID, MAX(TRANSFER_DATE) maxDATE
            FROM tableName
            GROUP BY AssetID
        ) b ON a.AssetID = b.AssetID AND
                a.Transfer_Date = b.maxDATE
```

*follow-up question: what is the basis for the record you want to be unique? the `ASSET_ID` or `TRANSFER_FROM_ID and TRANSFER_TO_ID`?*

Comment: Thank you for replying.
I want the record on the basis of Transfer From Id plus the asset id.

Comment: does it answer your question? you have'nt answer my follow up question :)

Comment: My requirement is actually to provide an option to search by username and asset category  where the user can search the asset possessed by each user such that only the latest information is shown.

Comment: by user means column `TRANSFER_FROM_ID`?

Comment: I edited a bit and got the result as I wanted.Thank you for all the help.
    
    `SELECT  A.*
    FROM    VIK_AM_ASSET_TRANSFER a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT STOCK_TAG, MAX(TRANSFER_DATE) maxDATE
            FROM VIK_AM_ASSET_TRANSFER
           GROUP BY STOCK_TAG
        ) B ON A.STOCK_TAG = B.STOCK_TAG
        AND 
                a.Transfer_Date = b.maxDATE;`